# Equivalent condition for projection onto a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $E : V \to V$ is a projection onto $M$. Prove that $E = proj_M$ if and only
if $||E(x)|| ≤ ||x||$ for all $x ∈ V$ . (It may be useful to use that $E = proj_M$ if and only if
$im(E)^⊥ = ker E$).

I have no idea how to prove the reverse of this, a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: One side is easy. Hint: write $x = x_E + x_{E^\bot}$ and inspect $|x|^2 = \langle x, x \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple: When you want to prove something like $M^{\perp} =\ker E,$ you show both inclusions. And to show each inclusion, the only thing you can do is just unravel definitions to get a vector $x$ (which belongs to one of $M^{\perp}, \ker E$ and which you want to show also belongs to the other) and a vector $m \in M,$ and somehow you need to build a contradiction out of them.

Suppose $||Ex|| \leq ||x||$ and $E$ is a projection onto $M.$ We wish to show that $E$ is the orthogonal projection onto $M.$

First, take $x \in M^{\perp},$ the orthogonal complement to $M.$ We argue $Ex = 0.$ Assume not; let $Ex = m \neq 0.$ Then $x \neq 0,$ so wlog scale so that we may assume $||x|| = 1.$ We have that $||m|| = ||Ex|| \leq ||x|| = 1.$

Now take $y = x + (\lambda-1)m.$ We find that $Ey = E(x+\lambda m - m) = Ex + (\lambda-1) Em = \lambda m,$ since $Ex = m$ and $Em = m$ as $E$ is a projection onto $M.$ We therefore have that $\lambda||m|| = ||Ey|| \leq ||y||.$ Squaring,
$$\lambda^2||m||^2 \leq ||x||^2 + (\lambda-1)^2||m||^2 = 1 + \lambda^2||m||^2 - 2\lambda ||m||^2 + ||m||^2$$
since $x, m$ are orthogonal. We can rewrite this as
$$(2\lambda - 1)||m||^2 \leq 1,$$
which must be true for every $\lambda.$ But this can only be true for every $\lambda$ if $||m|| = 0,$ and so $m = 0.$ Therefore every element of the orthogonal complement of $M$ is in the kernel of $E.$

Now we just argue that every element of the kernel of $E$ is orthogonal to $M.$ In finite-dimensions, this is trivial from the preceding observation by rank-nullity. In infinite-dimensions, this can be seen as follows. Assume that $x \in \ker E,$ so that $Ex = 0.$ If $x=0$ then obviously $x\in M^{\perp}.$ If $x\neq 0,$ then by scaling we can assume wlog that $||x|| = 1$ when trying to show that $x\in M^{\perp}.$

If $x \not\in M^{\perp},$ there's some $m \in M$ so that $||m|| = 1$ and $(x, m) \neq 0.$ Without loss of generality, we may assume that $(x, m) > 0,$ since otherwise just reflect $m.$

The parallelogram rule gives us
$$||x-\lambda m||^2 = ||x||^2 + \lambda^2||m||^2 - 2\lambda(x, m).$$
We have that
$$||E(x-\lambda m)||^2 \leq ||x-\lambda m||^2,$$
so that
$$\lambda^2||m||^2 \leq ||x||^2 + \lambda^2||m||^2 - 2\lambda(x,m),$$
or
$$2\lambda (x, m) \leq ||x||^2 = 1,$$
$$\lambda \leq \frac{1}{2(x,m)}$$
(recalling that $(x,m) > 0$). So if we pick $\lambda$ sufficiently small we get a contradiction!

(Note that in finite-dimensions by rank nullity you only need to do one of these two inclusions; in infinite-dimensions you need both, however.)